# Is there a UPnP Library for .NET (C# or VB.NET)?

Tags: .net, networking, upnp

I'm working on a P2P application, and I need to get it to communicate through NAT Routers / Firewalls using UPnP. However, it doesn't seem that the .NET Framework includes support for UPnP.

Is there a UPnP Library for .NET? C# or VB.NET?

UPDATE: I have since found the NATUPnP 1.0 Type Library (NATUPNP.DLL) COM Component that is part of Windows (since Windows XP) that allows you to easily setup/maintain Port Forwarding using UPnP.

I wrote an article with code samples here:
[.NET Framework: Communicate through NAT Router via UPnP (Universal Plug and Play)](http://pietschsoft.com/post.aspx?id=31200e6d-4b61-48b8-a9cb-91e3dd8e97f3)

Comment: Hey thank you for the exhaustive article and the project. I am trying it out and it works brilliantly on a 32bit Win7 system - however on a 64bit Win7 system, UPnPNATHelper.StaticPortMappings is always NULL. Would you have any insights on this?

Comment: The link in Chris post has rotted.  Here's a fresh link:
https://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/02/05/net-framework-communicate-through-nat-router-via-upnp

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a COM library that's easy enough to access:

> **[UPnP APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382303.aspx) Purpose**
>
> The UPnP™ framework enables dynamic
>   networking of intelligent appliances,
>   wireless devices, and PCs. There are
>   two APIs for working with
>   UPnP-certified devices:
>
> The **Control Point API**, which consists
>   of a set of COM interfaces used to
>   find and control devices. The **Device
>   Host API**, which consists of a set of
>   COM interfaces used to implement
>   devices that are hosted by a computer.

Comment: I wrote an article with code samples here: .NET Framework: Communicate through NAT Router via UPnP (Universal Plug and Play) - http://pietschsoft.com/post.aspx?id=31200e6d-4b61-48b8-a9cb-91e3dd8e97f3

Comment: @ChrisPietschmann link is dead as of Sept 14, 2012

Comment: @Urda, the link is working (again). The Wayback Machine link: http://web.archive.org/web/20130813184633/http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/02/05/NET-Framework-Communicate-through-NAT-Router-via-UPnP

Answer (score 25):

I have a written a fully Managed UPnP library around the microsoft UPnP Control Point COM objects, its available with full source and a demo project, you can download it from a GitHub repository here:

https://github.com/jogibear9988/ManagedUPnP

It supports full traversal of the UPnP description documents using an object heirachy and among other things is very easy to use.

Comment: This looks very promising, I'll give this a go in my project.

Comment: it's nice, but the underlying objects seem broken. device finder never sends the discovery packet.

Comment: @Aaron Murgatroyd  Your link is dead.
Here's a git hub fork:
https://github.com/jogibear9988/ManagedUPnP

Answer (score 8):

Mono.Nat is a pretty good library for upnp, at least for my case I had less issues with it so far than when I was using NATUPnP.

You can download it [here](http://projects.qnetp.net/projects/show/mono-nat) and you can find a decent tutorial on how to operate it at http://www.fluxbytes.com/csharp/upnp-port-forwarding-the-easy-way/

Answer (score 5):

This Intel UPnP tools have been re-released as open source tools at: http://opentools.homeip.net. The new tools are called the "Developer Tools for UPnP technologies". They are built in C# but there is a free code generator that will output C and C# stacks. The C stack will work on Windows and Linux.

Ylian

Comment: @user230486 Yilan, you really need to turn this stuff into a COM .dll or .ocx so people using VB6 or Delphi (or any other non.NET Win32 designer) can use all this work you've put into it. The current upnp.dll is a nightmare of a control and I wouldn't wish having to use it on my worst enemy, please create a Com Wrapper at least.

Answer (score 5):

Was looking around for this stuff personally and found::

mono-upnp:: https://github.com/mono/mono-upnp

Mono.Nat:: https://github.com/mono/Mono.Nat

Answer (score 3):

I use this, which seems to work fine:

http://code.google.com/p/dotnetportmapper/

Answer (score 3):

[Intels UPNP Tools](http://www.intel.com/cd/ids/developer/asmo-na/eng/downloads/upnp/index.htm) used to be able to export UPnP clients in C#.  The suite is deprecated but ought still work.

Answer (score 3):

If someone needs an easy library, I wrote a c# class library that uses the UPnPLib COM component. It has some basic functions to open and close ports. I haven't tested it on multiple platforms yet, but it works on Visual Studio 2010 in Windows 7. Feel free to download it at http://sourceforge.net/projects/easyupnp/

Comment: https://github.com/meehi/EasyUPnP

Answer (score 3):

For NAT specifically there is Mono.Nat.