# Does Microsoft have a .net class that uses UPnP in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, upnp, dhcp, mdns

I have been looking for a way to implement UPnP.  I have a need for it to run on Windows Compact Environment 7 (WEC7), but in order to test it easily, I want to set up a lab using regular Laptop computers and using the .net framework and coding in C#.  I found NATUPNP.DLL which is a COM component from Microsoft that supports UPnP, but documentation on it is about 3 years old and I am guessing that there is something newer out there.  I am hoping somebody knows the name of a class I can use (hopefully created and supported directly by Microsoft) that will work in C# with the .net framework that is not a COM component.

If you know of such a class, please let me know.  Also, please let me know what support Microsoft offers for UPnP on the WEC7 operating system.

Thanks,
Curtis

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee500769.aspx) ?

Comment: I gave you a Plus on your comment for that one.  It is for WEC7.  I would like to first try an implementation under Windows 7 and Windows XP using C# with .net.  I can't seem to find a simple UPnP implementation written by Microsoft for C# without using their COM .dll

Comment: There's a few suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/333079/124386

Comment: I was just looking at managedupnp.codeplex.com.  It looks good but wasn't written by Microsoft.  It's not directly part of the .net framework.  Surely Microsoft has some sort of non COM support of UPnP in their .net framework...  I just can't seem to find it...

Comment: @Curtis There is NO direct support for UPnP in the .NET framework... basically you either implement it yourself (NOT recommended) or use some 3rd-party library (some free, some commercial out there)...

Comment: @Curtis BTW: [this](http://managedupnp.codeplex.com/) uses the COM component under the hood...

Comment: If you'd consider third party libraries, see [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801134/upnp-library-for-net/7402910#7402910).  The answers include at least two libraries that are deployed elsewhere and well supported.