# Automatic way of enabling the access to port 4900 from the internet

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking, p2p

I am writing a custom p2p program that runs on port 4900. In some cases when the person is behind a router, this port is not accessible from the internet.

Is there an automatic way of enabling the access to the port from the internet. I am not really sure of how other p2p applications work.

Can anyone please throw some light on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a UPnP Library for .NET (C# or VB.NET)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333079/is-there-a-upnp-library-for-net-c-or-vb-net)

Comment: @David I disagree on the duplicate, though UPnP is indeed 'the' answer.

Comment: @jv42: Fair enough, which is why closing requires 5 votes.  At the very least, it points the OP to useful and related information.  I think StackOverflow etiquette prefers linking duplicates in this manner over re-posting the same answer.  But I can see where these two differ enough.  Either way, as long as the OP is helped, mission accomplished :)

Comment: @David: I can see the point. As a user, I do prefer to have a straight answer to the question, even if it points the 'duplicate' with a very short explanation.

Comment: I have posted my question, related to yours, but not precisly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54118006/vpn-with-webrtc-stun-ice

Answer (score 135, accepted):

P2P connectivity in a nutshell. Assume we're talking about UDP here.  The steps below can also be applied to TCP with some adjustments.

1. Enumerate all your local IP addresses (usually only 1).  Create a UDP socket on a given port number** for each adapter with an IP address.
2. For each socket created in step 1, contact a STUN or TURN server with that same socket to discover your external IP address and to discover what the internal port number maps to outside of the NAT (it's not always the same port value).  That is, your local address 192.168.1.2:4900 might be 128.11.12.13:8888 to the outside world.  And some NATs don't always use the same port mapping when using the same local port to other IP addresses.  TURN will also provide you a "relay address".  You can also use UPNP to get a port mapped address directly from your router, if it supports that protocol.
3. Through a rendezvous service (SIP, XMPP, instant message, web service, email, cups with strings), publish your address candidate list to a service or send a notification to the other client that says, "hey, I want to connect with you".  This message includes all the "address candidates" (ip and port pairs) collected in steps 1 and 2.
4. The remote client, upon receiving the invite to connect, performs step 1 and 2 above as well.  Then sends back his candidate list through the same channel that he received the inviter's candidate list on.
5. Hole punching step. Both clients, start sending test messages over UDP to the other side's address candidates and listening for the same messages on their end. Whenever a messages is received, reply back to the address from which it came. Eventually, the clients will discover that they have a pair of addresses that they can reliably send datagrams too. Typically, one endpoint makes the final decision on which address pair (sockets) to communicate with and the protocol facilitates this endpoint telling the other endpoint this decision.

**- usually best to not to rely on a well known port for P2P clients.  Because two clients behind the same NAT or firewall would not likely be able to use your software at the same time.

Here is a quick summary of some technologies to explore.

[STUN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN) - Is a simple server and protocol for clients behind a NAT/route to discover what their external IP and port mappings are.

[TURN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TURN) is an expansion to STUN, but supports relaying for P2P connectivity scenarios where firewalls and NATs prevent direct connections.

[ICE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Connectivity_Establishment) is a set of steps by which STUN and TURN are used for setting up a P2P connection. ICE is a formal protocol for steps 1-5 above. Two excellent set of slides on ICE are [here](http://www.jdrosen.net/uploads/1/5/0/0/15008848/ice-basic-tutorial.pptx) and [here](http://www.jdrosen.net/uploads/1/5/0/0/15008848/ice-ietf-tutorial2.pptx).

[WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) is a variant of the ICE standard as well as a reference library for make P2P sessions with STUN and TURN.

[UPNP + Internet Gateway Device Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Gateway_Device_Protocol) - Some routers support this for hosts to automatically obtain port mappings.

[libnice](http://nice.freedesktop.org/wiki/) is an open source C library for Linux (and might work on windows) that implements ICE.

[libjingle](http://code.google.com/apis/talk/libjingle/index.html) is another ICE implementation (in C++) from Google. For Windows and Linux.

[PJNATH](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Using_Standalone_ICE) is a library within the [PJSIP](http://www.pjsip.org/) suite of coding libraries. It is a good implementation of an ICE stack (C code) and has been ported to a lot of platforms. (Windows, Linux, Mac, iOS, Symbian, and soon Android).

And finally, I have a blatant plug for you to use [my STUN server code base](https://github.com/jselbie/stunserver).

Comment: @selbie , can STUN/TURN/ICE implementation work if one of, or both the peers are behind **Double NAT**?

Comment: @jagsgediya - yes. Most likely will converge through TURN.

Comment: @selbie I'm still unclear how the stuff work. Assuming that STUN server returned `128.11.12.13:8888 ` for Natted ip and port `192.168.1.2:4900 ` Assuming that I want to expose my port 3000 to the outside world.  Do I port forward all request arriving at port 4900 to port 3000

Comment: If you are trying to run a dedicated server than any client can connect to, then none of this stuff applies. You just open up a port on your router and firewalls as you described.  If you are trying to dynamically establish a temporary short-term connection with another computer without manually configuring your NAT, then the P2P instructions above apply.

Answer (score 5):

There are solutions in some cases, see UPnP: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play#NAT_traversal

My home router allows this, basically, the NAT can be configured automatically by the proper request from the computer.

I would not count on this to provide a big improvement in your availability, because not that many routers both support that and have it enabled.

EDIT: @David suggested this SO question for a .NET library for UPnP: [Is there a UPnP Library for .NET (C# or VB.NET)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333079/is-there-a-upnp-library-for-net-c-or-vb-net)

Answer (score 3):

I would use **WebRTC** technology as an open source framework for such application.

**[Official Website](http://www.webrtc.org/)**

In fact it is an open source project which supports all necessary for peer-to-peer technologies out of the box:

- ICE and STUN (NAT traversal)
- DTLS and SRTP (security)
- AVPF for quality of streaming.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a little more complicated than what you're looking for, but TCP Hole Punching is a technique that should work.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching

Alternatively, UPnP works great for routers / firewalls that support it.

Answer (score 1):

You have another option that is [NAT Port Mapping Protocol (NAT-PMP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_Port_Mapping_Protocol)
NAT-PMP is widely used by VoIP applications like Skype or  BitTorrent P2P clients.

Comment: Successor being [Port Control Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_Control_Protocol).

Answer (score -1):

For the simple beginnig I would recommend to see hole punching technique. Great video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TiMeoQt3K4g&t=315s). But be sure it will not always work relating the network topology. This solves the ICE technique which discovers how connection could be established.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).