# If firewalls don't accept incoming connections by default how do p2p networks work?

Tags: p2p, firewall, bittorrent

If firewalls block all incoming connections by default how do p2p technologies work? Like torrents, how do you connect to everyone who shares a file and get the information from them? Does it go through a relay server or something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523330/programming-p2p-application/8524609#8524609

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not up on everything about BitTorrent, as I am about general P2P connectivity techniques.  Typically clients in a P2P network rendezvous on a common signaling server (e.g. SIP, XMPP, tracking server, web site) to exchange IP addresses,other meta data, and messages to bootstrap direct connections.  Then use any of the following techniques below to get a communications session going:

- Both sides attempt to connect to each other simultaneously - in case one side can't accept incoming connections, but is allowed to make outbound connections. Such is the case for the firewall scenario.
- Hole punching (used in conjunction with above). Relays are not required per se, but do help insure connectivity when both peers are behind network devices that are difficult to traverse. There's both [UDP Hole Punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching) as well as [TCP Hole Punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching) techniques.  More info [here](http://www.bford.info/pub/net/p2pnat/index.html).
- Relays, including [TURN servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traversal_Using_Relays_around_NAT), can be deployed into a P2P network when direct connectivity is not possible. All your favorite video call applications deploy relays for these scenarios, but do their best to get peers directly connected to avoid the cost of relaying.

Bing for the following topics: STUN, TURN, ICE (Interactive Connectivity Establishment), libjingle, pjnath, libnice.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501359/p2p-message-transfer-behind-firewalls-and-nat 

could you please read this questions and help me a bit ?

Comment: for BT the signaling server is known as a tracker.

Comment: For the first point, it's hard to find documentation about it. You're right for the second point, Hole Punching, that's described in [Vuze DHT Additional Fetures](https://wiki.vuze.com/w/Distributed_hash_table#Additional_Features) and based on a concept of Rendez-Vous nodes from [Vuze Swarm Discoveries documentation](https://wiki.vuze.com/w/Swarm_Discoveries#Introduction). For the last point, STUN/TURN is [not implemented, at least in Vuze](http://vote.vuze.com/forums/170588-general/suggestions/3101012-implement-stun-t).

Answer (score 6):

If a firewall (as opposed to a NAT) intends to block incoming connections (which I believe they normally do), there's nothing you can do about it. You can try all the hole punching you like. This is achieved by just implementing a symmetric NAT, i.e. each pin-hole is open specifically for a ip,port-quadruple (source, destination port and IP).

BitTorrent is not likely to stop working just because you can't receive incoming connections, it will just be performing slightly worse. Chances are that there are at least some people on the swarm that can receive connections, and you just connect to them.

[This](http://bt.degreez.net/firewalled.html) is an old explanation of how being firewalled mostly just means worse performance.

**EDIT:**

The short answer to the "why" is that the majority of peers are not behind firewalls (just NATs).

Comment: Could you elaborate on http://bt.degreez.net/firewalled.html ? How did they get "that peers with open ports receive 2.4 times as much attention as those whose ports are blocked"?

Comment: because you will have more peer connections (at least you have more potential peer connections) if you can receive incoming connection attempts. That number is't applicable to swarms in general, but to their example in particular.

Comment: It would seem that the number would be slightly < 2 in that case, not 2.4 (cf. [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48193512/1429450)).

Comment: In the example of 6 firewalled peers and 6 peers with open ports, a firewalled peer is connected to 6 peers. Each of those peers have 11 connections (to all other peers), which means the "attention" you get is 1/11th from 6 peers = 6/11th. If you're not firewalled, you get 5/11th from the other open peers and also 1/6 attention from 6 peers. the result is 1 5/11th of "attention" versus 6/11th = 1 5/11th divided by 6/11th = 1.454545 / 0.545454 ~= 2.6

Answer (score 2):

For posterity:

Short answer is, it's done via https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)

When you connect to google.com from your machine (which most likely sits behind a router and NAT) your machines IP address and NAT'ed port number get sends to google servers. Google uses these connection info to send search results to your machine.

You can think of google's servers similar to one node in the p2p network. Google were able to 'reach' you from their servers even though your router doesn't accept incoming connection. It's because they didn't initiate the connection (they don't know your ip:NATedport combination to initiate a connection). But your machine can make outbound connections and send/publish your ip:NATedport combo to outside world.

So both nodes in the p2p send their ip:NATedport combo to a third party site and exchange this info and start connecting (whoever got the info first) to one another.

Answer (score -1):

Let
*F* = # firewalled nodes,
*O* = # nodes with open incoming port,
*T* = *F* + *O* = total # of nodes,
*P* = *O* / *T* = fraction of total nodes that have open ports,
*C<sub>f</sub>* = max # connections each firewalled node can have, and
*C<sub>o</sub>* = max # connections each open node can have.

Then,
*C<sub>f</sub>* = *O*, <sup>∵ firewalled nodes can only connect to open nodes</sup>
*C<sub>o</sub>* = *T* - 1, <sup>∵ open nodes can connect to all other nodes (and once all the firewalled nodes have first connected to them)</sup>
so
*C<sub>o</sub>* / *C<sub>f</sub>* = (*T* - 1) / *O* = 1 / *P* - 1 / *O*.

If *T* is large,
*C<sub>o</sub>* / *C<sub>f</sub>* ≈ 1 / *P*.

So, for example, say half the nodes have open incoming ports: *P* = ½. Then,
*C<sub>o</sub>* / *C<sub>f</sub>* ≈ 2,
which means that open nodes have ~2× the number of connections as firewalled nodes  (meaning they are overburdened, but also meaning they have more visibility).

Thus, it is better for particular nodes and for the entire network to have *P* = 1; all nodes will be equally visible and equally burdened.

If *P* = 0, the network won't work at all ∵ no one will be able to initiate connections to other peers.

Comment: Great symbolic logic flex but you're missing the whole point of the question. Modern networking equipment employed at all network levels, whether it be inside an ISP's infrastructure or on the end user's network, have a default routing configuration whereby any and all unsolicited, incoming traffic is dropped. If you want to run a web server or anything that would require ingress of unsolicited traffic then you'd need to talk to your ISP and have them config their hardware to allow ingress of such traffic. This wasn't always the case, it's just a  widely employed means of curtailing spam.