# Low-latency peer to peer udp tunneling library?

Tags: networking, udp, p2p

I am interested in developing a peer-to-peer network that uses UDP tunneling to get around NAT for low-latency communication for something similar to a multiplayer game.  There will be central server available for authentication and identifying external IP addresses.  Is there an open source library out there with a LGPL or BSD (etc) license?  I'd like to avoid reinventing the wheel if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following open source libraries are all variants or direct implementations of ICE for P2P NAT traversals scenarios for UDP.

[PJNATH](http://www.pjsip.org/pjnath/docs/html/)

[libnice](http://nice.freedesktop.org/wiki/)

[libjingle](https://developers.google.com/talk/libjingle/)

I've been using pjnath and find it to be quite good, robust, and has the widest platform support.

See my classic answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8524609/104458) on the basics of UDP NAT tranersal and P2P.

Comment: This project wound up on the back burner for a long time but I have settled on libjingle with XMPP backend.  I guess it is now WebRTC.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at zeroMQ, it's a simple library that encapsulates TCP/UDP networking for creaeting distributed protocols. 
There is bindings for every language.

For P2P you can use these modes:

- PGM/EPGM for discover member of P2P on your LAN (it use multicast)
- REQ/REP for ask a question to one member
- PULL/PUSH for duplicate one resource on the net
- Publish/subscribe for transmission a file to all requesters

Comment: I took a look at zeroMQ, but I didn't see any UDP tunneling abilities to handle NATs.