# Choosing port number for UDP hole-punching

Tags: udp, port, p2p, nat, hole-punching

I have a weird problem. I have a successfully working C++ (boost asio) P2P application which works on most of the NAT. The problem is when I give the initial start port number as 1000 it checks if 1000 is free else increment by one and chooses a port and starts handshaking. But when I have 10000, 20000, or any other huge port number the hole punching doesn't work on port restricted cone NAT.

How is that possible? I am pretty sure it nothing to do with the code. and recently it doesn't work on one of my friends' full cone NAT as well, but it has worked in many other full cone NATs. What could be the reason? Is there something I am missing about how a NAT behaves?

Comment: [RFC 5389](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5389) warns against the use of STUN as a *complete NAT traversal* solution.  It doesn't have complete references on why, but whatever the reasons, it maybe relevant to you.  Especially see chapter 2.

Comment: Actually, the problem is likely that STUN (or TURN) aren't being used to begin with.  @Navin  - how are your endpoints discovering their port mappings?  If you aren't using anything resembling STUN and TURN, how do you obtain an ip/port mapping to share with the endpoint in establishing P2P?

Comment: @artlessnoise i am not using STUN service, i am using my own server to get the endpoint

Comment: @selbie actually i am using my own server to get both endpoints.STUN is used to check what type of NAT i am behind and it will give us our own public enpoint, i don't want to check what type of NAT i am behind because it's time consuming, so i use my own server to get the public IP and port and share it with both side.. it works perfectly.. Does STUN do anything more than that
?

Answer (score 3):

1. In many NAT implementations, there are protection rules in place which prevent one host from tying up a large percentage of ports on the WAN interface, e.g. like described [here](http://help.stonesoft.com/onlinehelp/StoneGate/SMC/5.3.5/SGAG/SGOH_TroubleshootingMessages/Requested_NAT_Cannot_Be_Done.htm).
2. Depending on the router, the NAT table entries have different lifetimes, and there are always limits on how many ports can be allocated to a single client (I've seen numbers from 128 to 4096).

So I think when you get to the point where you need to use high ports, the NAT table for your source IP address is already full (or almost full) with entries from old connections, or connections from other apps, so the router either decides to decline or can't fit the new NAT entry for your port.

However, to be sure, I would try to repeat that on a controlled environment collecting Wireshark dumps on both sides of the NAT and analyze the packets. If possible, it would also be helpful to enable router logs and peek into them.

I understand this is not a "magic bullet", but hope it somehow helps you.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to choose the port number yourself. The operating system can do this faster and better than your code can.

Bind your socket to port 0 and let the OS choose an available port number for you.  You didn't specify what programming language, but it usually involves a call to [getsockname](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getsockname.2.html)() after the bind() call is made to discover what local port is going to be used.  Java and .NET have equivalent APIs for doing the same thing.

Then follow all the other steps here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8524609/104458

Comment: The programming language is C++ and boost sockets are used for portability. I tried doing that but i had a problem connecting to port restricted cone NAT. So after a very long tiring day i found out that if i give a port number specifically then it works. So i try from 1000 to 10000, i know it's weird but works

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this'll help but have you tried having one instance of the client application starting at 1001 and the other starting at 1000, then both increment by 1.

While the 1000 will fail on client B, client A has already tried 1001 and so punched that hole, so hopefully it'll work, right? In theory, it sounds OK in my head.