# STUN protocol questions

Tags: traversal, nat, stun

I am working on a project which needs p2p connection which I am planning to use XMPP jingle XEP_0176

But I am confused about how STUN works (I mean the flow).

For example, I have two clients A and B.

Client A as the initiator, and Client B as the responder, and I am using google's stun server for this example.

Client A has a LAN IP of 192.168.0.3 port 9887 then Client A sends a binding request to the google's stun server which responded 114.123.123.123 port 9987

Client B has a LAN IP of 192.168.22.1 port 9999 and client B does the same binding request too, and recevied 256.118.118.118 port 9999.

At this point, how can I establish the peer connection? What do I need to do or am I missing anything here?

Comment: I've answered this question several times before.  You can read the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8524609/104458

Comment: selbie,
Thanks for the post, Do the STUNTMAN includes TURN server functionality?

Comment: Stunman is STUN only. My TURN server recommendation is rfc5766-turn-server: http://code.google.com/p/rfc5766-turn-server/

Comment: Selbie, Thanks for the help. I m trying to build a NAT Traversal solution in python, iOS, js and android.

Comment: Are there any useful libraries that I can look into? Cheers.