# how to make a point-to-point VoIP call in android

Tags: java, android, voip, p2p

I am searching for a way to **develop** an android app to make a point-to-point VoIP call between two Android devices without having any intermediate server (SIP server).devices have access to internet. Is this possible?

- we know the IP address of the devices
- should we create a local sip account ? if yes How ?
- is there any android library for creating local SIP account ?
  -

Answer (score 1):

Making P2P call is not relevant to any platform. There are protocols for that which you implement with any language you want. There are several protocols for that. Currently ICE protocol is the best option available.

Also note that 100% P2P is not possible. For some scenario your call will be established through relay server.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523330/programming-p2p-application/8524609#8524609) explains how to make a P2P connection.