# Basic udp NAT traversal in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, udp, stun

Its easy to open a udp-connection in nodejs with dgram, i also get the my clients ( pc in homenetwork )  public ip via my webhosted server, but this 'aquired' ip doesnt resolve if i want to connect to client from another client ( using different ports ) from within my homenetwork. What am I mssing out here? Doesnt STUN work like this?

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8524609/104458

Comment: STUN is basically a service for identifying your public IP address.  Connecdtivity is basically established by attempting to "connect" on both the private IP address that the OS provides as well as the public ip address and port obtained by stun.