# UDP hole punching between two clients on one machine

Tags: udp, nat, hole-punching

I do [UDP hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching) using the following method: I have a lobby server L, and two clients A and B behind a (shared) NAT.

Now, A and B are running on the same machine. They both send a datagram to server L.

Server L tells both A and B the IP+PORT of the other.
Note that the IPs of A and B that the server sees are identical, but the ports are different, as expected.

Then A and B send a datagram to each other, using the server provided addr+port.

Yet, their datagrams to each other never arrive.

My question: does UDP hole punching work if both clients are on the same machine? What if they are just on the same LAN, behind the same NAT?

*NOTE:* I tried to lower the strictness of my router, but [Archer C7](https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/wifi-router/archer-c7/) does not seem to have a selection for Cone/Symmetric/Asymmetric unfortunately. I did switch off Stateful Packet Inspection.

*UPDATE*: When I try sending punch datagrams, I do see this come by over the network device:

```
ICMP dest unrch (port)
```

*UPDATE*: stunclient output:

```
$ stunclient --mode full stunserver.stunprotocol.org
Binding test: success
Local address: 10.0.1.2:49703
Mapped address: 209.161.250.218:49703
Behavior test: success
Nat behavior: Endpoint Independent Mapping
Filtering test: success
Nat filtering: Address and Port Dependent Filtering
```

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8524609/104458

Comment: What is the NAT type of `A` and `B`?  Run `stunclient --mode behavior stun.stunprotocol.org` to find out. Code [here](http://www.stunprotocol.org)