# How to get external port from stun server

Tags: java, sockets, p2p, nat, stun

How to get external ip and port from stun server? For example Google's stun server, `stun.l.google.com`

So I can use that to establish P2P connection with sockets between clients behind NAT.

Currently, I can only connect to peers in local network, but I want to connect peers outside of local network with sockets.

Comment: You'll need a STUN library and a service for exchanging address candidates: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8524609/104458

Comment: How can I request a stun server my ip and port with sockets? I want a code implementation in Java

Comment: How to use JSTUN library?

Comment: JSTUN is the answer you seek.

Comment: There is no documentation for JSTUN. I am getting exceptions. Can you give a code snippet of it?

Comment: Start by compiling jstun library and the sample apps yourself and running it. Then step through it with a debugger - you'll quickly see the class hierarchy.

Comment: Please give a code snippet of the function that takes socket or port number and returns external ip and port.

Comment: I want to use Google's stun server, stun.l.google.com

Comment: Start with the JSTUN sample code here to run the "Discovery Test" or the "Fast Discovery Test" client code.  It's all here: https://github.com/tking/JSTUN/tree/master/src/main/java/de/javawi/jstun/test/demo

Comment: How to get InetAddress for constructor?

Comment: Sonu.  Learn how to send UDP packets first using Java's network and socket libraries.