# How to use WebRTC in a C++ application?

Tags: c++, webrtc

I'm trying to write a C++ command line program for peer-to-peer file transfer. My idea is to establish a connection with another machine, and send file data directly. My target platform is Windows, but interoperability with Linux and MacOS would be nice. I want this program to be standalone and not require a web browser.

I did some research and it seems that WebRTC would fit the bill, but I can't find much information on using it with C++.

Is it possible to build a standalone executable that utilizes WebRTC without requiring users to download any dependencies in order to use my program?

Comment: start here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8524609/104458

Comment: While I sympathise with your situation, it feels like you first need to ask about generic technologies before asking about a specific implementation. To improve your question, I would suggest you remove the mention of WebRTC and instead present your use-case and ask for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

As the name suggests - to have the "RTC", it requires "Web" component, either in form of browser or a library.

The C++ library is quite huge and it's not a trivial task to understand and write it in a short period. Browser provides APIs in form of JavaScript calls, which are relatively easier to implement.

There might be commercial APIs in C++ available over internet.